# How to pass <list_items> to a PULLDOWN DIALOG as a variable?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

In a PRACTICE script, how do I pass a list of items to a pulldown dialog as a variable. I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
&myFiles="foo,bar,baz"

DIALOG
(
    OptionA.SEL: PULLDOWN &myFiles ""
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **PRACTICE Script Language User’s Guide** (`practgice_user.pde`):

> Use (**&** or (**&+** as opening block delimiter to switch ON macro expansion ...

The following works as expected:

```
&myFiles="foo,bar,baz"

DIALOG
(&+ ; <-- note this
    OptionA.SEL: PULLDOWN &myFiles ""
)
```